# I want to remove "SMS and Call log permissions" under "Sensitive permissions and APIs" defined earlier app account on Google Play developer console

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

Earlier I had defined in my App Store listing settings over developer console under "App Content" >> "Sensitive permissions and APIs" >> "SMS and Call log permissions".
We had checked "default SMS handler" under this section for "android.permission.SEND_SMS" but now we have removed it as required for core functionality. Thus we want to set our settings as not using this.
On doing this we were not allowed to remove it as error message says "at least one should be checked" but We are unable to remove it.

Guide us in removing it from settings as now the app doesn't require this permission at all.